# How does VS Code use the help/insert key "normally" on macOS? (Not have it intercepted)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, insert, keyboard

I'm using macOS Catalina on an iMac with a WASD Keyboard configured for Mac use. The keyboard includes the usual PC keyboard bank of six keys of Insert/Home/Page Up and Delete/End/Page Down.

I run the current (auto updating) VS Code. It just works, including the Insert key for toggling Insert/Overwrite.

Most applications, including Terminal and Xquartz, can't see the Insert (Help) key.  No input is registered if you press the key.

How is VS Code able to see the Insert/Help key when pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, VS Code is not special.  Rather XQuartz has an option to enable key equivalents (Cmd-Q, Cmd-W, etc.) under X.  This also causes the interception of the Insert key.

You may disable this for behavior ALL X applications at once via the X11 Preferences or via the command:

`defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_key_equivalents -boolean false`

Reference: https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/Xquartz/